# Execute parent page function from within colorbox

Tags: ajax, colorbox

i am trying to execute a function that will run after colorbox close. This function is meant to update the underlying page by refreshing a select element on the page with the newly inserted values from the closed colorbox. I have read some where that I can run functions on the cbox_closed event. How do I reference the parent page's ajax function to update the 'select' element? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the ColorBox runs in the overall execution context of the parent. You should refer to the desired element as you would from other js in the parent.

For example, if the parent page had an element with an ID of 'myElement', you can refer to '#myElement' in a function executed via the cbox_closed event trigger.

For greater specificity, prefix the element like this **parent.elementID** or **parent.formname.elementID**.